# Jquery Show/Hide Multiple Table Rows

Tags: jquery, html-table, hide, rows, show

Trying to show/hide table rows using jquery. First two rows work. The third row doesn't display all data.

Jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vcolmenar/wG8qf/1/

HTML Data for the Table
    
    
        Main
        Data

```
<tr class="main">
    <td>
    <a href="#" class="main">12345</a>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class = "data">
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
        11111
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="main">
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="main">12345</a>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class = "data">
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
        11111
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="main">   
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="main">12345</a>
    </td>  
</tr>

<tr class = "data">
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
        11111
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class = "data">
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
        22222
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class = "data">
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
        33333
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class = "data">
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
        44444
    </td>
</tr>
```

JavaScript for Jquery show/hide function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Hide table rows with class 'min', but appear when clicked.
$(".data").hide();
$(".main").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().next(".data").toggle("fast");
});
});
```

Comment: there is no `.data` after your 3rd main

Comment: scratch that, looks like you just revised it and it looks like its working, whats the problem?

Comment: @SpYk3HH the last a.main only shows the first sibling tr.data, I think he wants all the tr.data rows between the tr.main entries

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## css

tr.data {display:none;}

## javascript

```
$(function(){
  $("#main-data-table","body").on({'click':function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("tr.main").nextUntil("tr.main").toggle("fast");
   }},
   "a.main",null);
});
```

## html

```
<table id="main-data-table">
<thead><tr>
    <th>Main</th>
    <th>Data</th>
</tr></thead>
<tfoot></tfoot>
<tbody>
<tr class="main">
        <td>
        <a href="#" class="main">12345</a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class = "data">
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            11111
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="main">
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="main">12345</a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class = "data">
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            11111
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="main">   
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="main">12345</a>
        </td>  
    </tr>

    <tr class = "data">
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            11111
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class = "data">
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            22222
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = "data">
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            33333
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = "data">
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            44444
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wG8qf/7/)

Comment: @DefyGravity Great man